# For Loop with UIButton Names

Tags: ios, for-loop, uibutton

I need to set default values on multiple buttons from a numbered array. Right now I am using an if statement but it is way too long and there must be a better way perhaps with a loop?

**Current Code**

```
    @interface HelpPage()

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box0;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box1;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box2;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box3;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box4;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *box5; 
    // I have over 120 buttons on this screen
    @end

    @implementation Help

    NSMutableArray *boxes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"helpboxeschecked"];
    NSInteger i;

    for (i=0; i < boxes.count; i++) {
        NSString *box = boxes[i];

        if ([box isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            [_box0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        if ([box isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            [_box1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        if ([box isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
            [_box2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        // and so on for all boxes
    }

   // **Isn't there a way to have it be** 

    for (i=0; i < boxes.count; i++) {

        if ([box[i] = i) {
            [_box[i] setImage:[UIIMage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add your buttons to an `IBOutletCollection` and set `tags` on your buttons and do something like:

```
...
for (UIButton *button in myButtonCollection) {
   if (button.tag == box.intValue) {
       // set image
   }
}
```

or just add them to an array:

```
NSArray *buttons = @[_box1, _box2 ...
```